# rotate image depending on user touch on screen

Tags: android

i am developing game.i am displaying gun object center bottom of the screen.when user tap on screen i need to rotate gun that direction.i done rotating image.but when user tap on screen i need to rotate image that direction.can you please help me

Thanks in advance

Aswan

Comment: Clarify you question. For what part do you need help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is your image a bitmap? could you convert it to one? Would an onClick listener not work and when the user clicks do something like.. http://www.anddev.org/resize_and_rotate_image_-_example-t621.html

Seeing some code as to what you've attempting would be nice also. The following will help you with checking if the bitmap has been clicked in case you're stuck on that also http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html . 
I've never attemped this myself but I think that would work. Try redrawing the bitmap when you have resized it.

Comment: not useful for me.already i done rotate image using matrix and all.my question is when user tap on screen i need to rotate image tap direction

Comment: So basically, just to clarify your question is not how to rotate an image but rather how to find out in which direction the user wants to move by picking up on their click?

Answer (score 0):

Just use onTouchListener for your View and use this code for that

```
     @Override
 public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    float currentX = event.getX();
    float currentY = event.getY();
    Log.i(TAG, "action type is"+event.getAction());
    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
        Log.i(TAG, "Entering in onTouch");
        double rotationAngleRadians = Math.atan2(currentX - dialer.centerX,      dialer.centerY - currentY);
        dialer.rotationAngle = (int) Math.toDegrees(rotationAngleRadians);
        Log.i(TAG, "rotaion angle"+dialer.rotationAngle);
        dialer.invalidate();
        return true;
    }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: what is `dailer` what data type?